# How to avoid creating of parasitic lexer rules in Antlr4?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

The grammar below works incorrectly.

The grammar is following:

```
program:
    (keyword |
    string |
    WS)*;

keyword: 'print';

string: QUOTE (CH | WS)*? QUOTE;

QUOTE: '\'';

WS  : [ \t\r\n]+;

CH: .;
```

The goal is to have langauge with both string literals and keywords.

The parsed string is follows:

```
print 'printed'
```

It should be parsed as keyword, then whitespace, then string literal.

It is parsed this way instead:

[image]

Obviously, it sees keyword `print` inside string literal. This is because it has implicitly created parasitic rule for "print".

How to avoid/overcome this?

I don't wish to specify, that string literal can contain keywords, because it is logically incorrect.

Also I can't specify DOT lexer meta operator, because I don't wish to allow every token contained inside quotes (I don't want quote to occur there).

So, what to do?

Answer (score 2):

If you separate your combined grammar into a separate `lexer grammar` and `parser grammar`, ANTLR will not allow you to implicitly define lexer rules via literals placed in a parser rule. If you want `print` to be a keyword, you would need to include this lexer rule (otherwise `'print'` would not be allowed in a parser rule):

```
PRINT : 'print';
```

The next step is to convert `string` from a parser rule to a lexer rule, such as this:

```
STRING : QUOTE ~'\''* QUOTE;
```

Comment: Thanks! But is it possible to add escape sequnces here, to allow strings to contain quotes?